# (Expected 2D, got 1D array instead): How do I slice the Data so that I get the Mpg column as a 2D array?

Tags: pandas, linear-regression

```
df1.head()
data = df1.drop(df1.columns[[1, 3]], axis = 1)
X = data.iloc[:, 0].values
y = data.iloc[:, :-1].values

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
data.head()
```

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cl5w.png)

**How do I slice the data so that I get the mpg column or X as a 2D array?**

I tried doing data.iloc[:, 0].values to get the index and mpg column (to form a 2D array), but the error still says: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches that you can use to fix this issue:

1. Convert Series to DataFrame so your data will have shape [n_rows, n_columns]: `X = data.iloc[:, 0].to_frame()`
2. Use `numpy.expand_dims()` to expand the shape of an array: `X = np.expand_dims(X, axis = -1)`